# Consulta a una BD con Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

verán, tengo una GUI en python que se encarga de buscar datos en una BD en sqlite. puedo hacer consultas sencillas pero ahora necesito mandar a llamar a todos los **"ID"** iguales y asignarles un mismo valor.

Estos son mis valores en la BD:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el programa necesito que Por Ejemplo: si en mi interfaz gráfica agrego un *"Hola"* y selecciono **"ID = 1"** se imprima *"Hola"*. en todos los países que tengan el mismo **"ID"**

Este es un ejemplo de consulta en mi programa donde (Combo1.get()) es un combobox donde elijo el **"ID"**:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('FutDB.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
query = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Equipos where ID=?",(Combo1.get(),))
```

Con esa consulta solo se agrega el "Hola" es un solo **"ID"** y no en todos como quisiera. Todo esto esta dentro de una función mayor y se ejecuta con un botón.

Gracias a todos y espero haberme explicado bien.

Comment: Es algo raro, si tu pones un cláusula `where` se te devolverá **todos** los datos que coincidan y no solo uno.

Comment: Estas haciendo cur.fetchone() o cur.fetchall()?

Comment: Supongo que quiere un cur.fetchall() y que al hacer la llamada todos los que tiene el id llamado que al no ser primary hay varios iguales y al poner en un entry= 'hola' se imprima al lado de todos los de id seleccionado. ¿Es eso lo que necesitas?

Comment: Es un  cur.fetchall() @DanteS.